# jQuery UI Slider - ajax result

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I am trying to implement a jQuery UI slider, where the slider value will be used to update a section of the page via ajax.

I can get the ajax to work, but I am having issues, getting the slider range to stay as the user has left it. Instead as soon as the slider handle is let go it pings back to default values.

Using jQuery 1.7.1, jQuery UI 1.8.16

Code:

```
$( "#example_slider" ).slider({
    range: true,
    step: 150,
    min: 0,
    max: 450,
    values: [ 0, 450 ],
    stop: function( event, ui ) {

        var value1 = ui.values[0];
        var value2 = ui.values[1];

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_file.php",
            data: "value1="+value1+"&value2="+value2,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("#content_update").html(html);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have other code that might be doing this? I see nothing wrong with your slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah my bad, Javascript initialization was also being called from ajax_file.php, which was why it was resetting the slider values. Removed this, and now works as expected.